# Excel custom format not kept after selection from list

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formatting

In an excel sheet I've created some custom dates. These dates are calculated from a formula used to fetch a series of days from a given week of the year.

The custom format I applied is **ddd, dd mmmm a.m.** and **ddd, dd mmmm p.m.** and they are listed in this way:

day1 a.m.

day1 p.m.

day2 a.m.

day2 p.m.

and so on...

Example:

Mon, 21 January 2020 a.m.

Mon, 21 January 2020 p.m.

Tue, 22 January 2020 a.m.

Tue, 22 January 2020 p.m.

These dates are then used in the main sheet of the document, in a drop-down list, so that the user can select the relevant date.

But while the custom format is displayed correctly in the list, it is not when a date is finally selected and it's automatically changed/converted to a standard date format.

Practically speaking, in the drop-down list I see **ddd, dd mmmm a.m.** (or p.m.) but when I select a date I see **ddd, dd mm yy**

I can't put a custom format to the cells because I don't know if the user will chose "a.m." or "p.m" and I can't convert to simple text as well because I will get the date in numbers (result from the formula).

I've also tried with conditional formatting but it doesn't work (or I'm using the wrong code...)

So my temporary workaround is erasing the formula on the cells and type manually the dates so they're seen as simple text and not converted, but of course it's not what I want...

Any suggestion on how to keep the custom date after selection from the list?

Comment: FYI using `ddd, dd mmmm AM/PM` as a custom date format works fine. And will display "Tue, 21 January AM".

Comment: @Plutian by doing that, it displays "AM" and never "PM"

Comment: This is depending on how your date it supplied. If you add a date and time, it will convert the time value into AM/PM instead. How do you get "a.m." in your data to begin with? Is this supplied as text?

Comment: @Plutian I see your point...only the date is calculated, the AM/PM was added by me as custom text by using "" ...in this way: ddd, dd mmmm "a.m."

Comment: In that case, rather than find a convoluted way to keep your custom format, you could add a mock time to your date instead(1:00 for AM, 13:00 for PM for example), and use the AM/PM custom format. If you want to calculate with the date later, you could use `Datevalue(` in your formula to trim the time when necessary.

Comment: @Plutian right, by using a mock time it should work as expected. Many thanks!!!